# Opening KMZ file from SNAP file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, kmz, sentinel-snap

I am struggling with this issue in [QGIS](https://www.qgis.org). I have a [KMZ](https://www.ogc.org/standards/kml) file contain three files (exported from SNAP).

1. legend.png
2. overlay.kml
3. overlay.png

I tried to open the KMZ and it doesn't work.
I tried to open the KML after unzip the KMZ, and it doesn't work.

This file is generated by SNAP and contains Phase information.

I exported the file from [SNAP](http://step.esa.int/main/download/) as [GeoTiFF](https://www.ogc.org/standards/geotiff) but the legend is not the same:

[image]

and this the GeoTIFF in QGIS:

[image]

I can't define a color scale like the original one.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: You said you exported your file as GeoTIFF but files extensions only show *.png and *.kml. Could you precise a little bit your workflow please?

Comment: I exported first time as KMZ and did't work !.
then I exported my image as GeoTiFF
1st image is the real one in SANP
2nd image is the GeoTiFF in QGIS

Comment: Could you provide the output of [`gdalinfo`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalinfo.html) on your GeoTIFF file?

Answer (score 1):

I added this custom .txt of color. First, I import directly the img from BEAM DIMAO product. And this is my color text you can import it as .txt to QGIS.

QGIS Generated Color Map Export File

```
INTERPOLATION:INTERPOLATED
-3.142,110,60,170,255,-3.142
-2.244,210,60,160,255,-2.244
-1.346,255,110,70,255,-1.346
-0.449,200,200,50,255,-0.449
0.449,80,245,100,255,0.449
1.346,25,200,180,255,1.346
2.244,60,130,220,255,2.244
3.142,100,70,190,255,3.142
```

[image]